# typo3 flow: "Result could not be converted to string" - get field content of query result

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, flow-framework

Good morning,

my repository looks like this:

```
public function findbyBeitrag($BS) {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals('name', $BS)
        );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

My controller looks like that:

```
public function findbyBeitragAction() {
     $BS = '1';
     $ergebnis = $this->beitragssatzRepository->findByBeitrag($BS);
     return . $ergebnis . '!';
}
```

The database looks like that:

```
     name     beitragssatz
     1        15,00
     2        30,00
     3        40,00
```

As result of the query I want to get "15,00". What do I have to add to the function in the repository to get as result of my query only the 15,00?
I get the error message "Result could not be converted to string".

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the var_dump of $ergebnis?

Comment: If I replace `return . $ergebnis . '!';` with `var_dump($ergebnis);` in the controller I get a strange output with much content like `object(TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\QueryResult)#1382 (2) { ["rows":protected]=> NULL ["query":protected]=> object(TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query)#1365 (18) { ["Flow_Aop_Proxy_targetMethodsAndGroupedAdvices":"TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query":private]=> array(2) { ["execute"]=> array(1) { ["TYPO ` and so on and my browser crashes.

Comment: use after execute(); $query->fetchAll(); this should fetch from database not the execute() then dump the result to check

Comment: I replaced `return $query->execute();` with `return $query->execute();$query->fetchAll();` in the function in the repository, but with the same output

Comment: $query = $this->createQuery(SELECT t.passiv FROM yourtable t); $query->getResult(); what about this, as for the documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html well singleScalarResult() is more appropriate if its only one expected result

Comment: ah didnt understood your table you need a parameter there Select t.beitragssatz from yourtable t where name = '.$BS.

Comment: I tried it in phpmyadmin with the sql-command `SELECT beitragssatz FROM itoop_atc_domain_model_beitragssatz WHERE name= 1` and that works; I got 15,00 as output. But I didn't get it work with typo3 flow / doctrine till now. I added some more rows in the database above in my question, so it should be easy for everybody to see, how my table looks like.

Comment: In table name use your entity name

Comment: I tried `$query = $this->createQuery('SELECT beitragssatz FROM itoop\atc\Domain\Model\Beitragssatz beitragssatz WHERE beitragssatz.name = 1');` but that doesn't work.

Comment: The same as before: `Object of class TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\QueryResult could not be converted to string in /var/www/apps/flow/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/itoop_atc_Controller_BeitragssatzController.php line 95`

Comment: Actually the returned object have 0 rows returned so it doesnt return anything from database there must be something wrong in the query the error is because you try to convert the whole result object to string when you concatenate, i am using symfony and my query tested with the fetchAll return data.. i need to go home later and test it maybe i can be of more help

Comment: I don´t want to return a row but a value! In my case I want to get the value "15,00" out of the colum beitragssatz in the row "1" So I want the query to return "15,00" and NOT the row " 1  15,00".

Comment: what $this refers to? you have access to entity manager?

Comment: for me this works perfectly : $query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT e.field FROM PathTo\Entity\Entity e WHERE o.id = 1520'); $query->getSingleScalarResult(); return one string variable which is my field.

Comment: With the kindly help of @NawfalSerrar I got it: To be able to execute arbitrary DQL in typo3 flow first I had to inject Doctrine's Entity Manger in my repository: `/**
 * @Flow\Inject
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
 */
protected $entityManager;`. Then with the following `$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT beitragssatz.beitragssatz FROM \itoop\atc\Domain\Model\Beitragssatz beitragssatz WHERE beitragssatz.name = '1'");` I got an output as array. Then with `$query->getSingleScalarResult();` and at last `return $query->execute();` I got the the wanted string!

Comment: btw you don't really need $query->execute() i always use $query->getSingleScalarResult() is enough because the execute is used when you bindParameter to the query and use prepare() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject Doctrine's Entity Manger in the repository:

```
/** * @Flow\Inject * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager */ 
protected $entityManager;
```

Then with the following :

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT beitragssatz.beitragssatz FROM \itoop\atc\Domain\Model\Beitragssatz beitragssatz WHERE beitragssatz.name = '1'");
```

I got an output as array. Then with

```
$query->getSingleScalarResult();
```